# ActionMailer email images broken in some clients

Tags: image, html-email, actionmailer

I'm using ActionMailer to send emails, and these emails include images. To include the images I'm using `<%= image_tag('email-logo.png') %>` and `config.action_controller.asset_host` in staging/production is set correctly.

These images appear fine in Outlook (I also tried it in a few temp email services, and they work there as well), but appear broken in Gmail, Apple Mail (desktop + iOS), and Mailbox app.

The encoding for the HTML version of the email is `quoted-printable`, is that correct?

When I inspect the raw email in Gmail, the markup for the image appears like:

```
  <img alt=3D"Site Logo" class=3D"logo" src=3D"//staging.mysite.come/ass=
ets/email-logo-98e7cf6a48a4f2186ab9de2dcdfaa4bf0.png" style=3D"width: 30=
px; display: inline; vertical-align: middle;" />
```

When I remove the `=` and load the URL in my browser it appears fine. Could the `=` be breaking it? Could it be the lack of protocol in the image URL?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the `=`. It's a *soft line break* in `quoted-printable` encoding used to comply with the 76 chars line length, and it is removed and the two lines joined when the text is decoded. See the [wikipedia page on Quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) for more info.

I suspect Gmail is not being able to prefetch the image. Gmail tries to prefetch the image and then serve it from their secure proxy servers. See [this official post](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com.ar/2013/12/images-now-showing.html) for more info about that. To do so, the image needs to have a publicly accessible url. A similar thing might be happening with the other clients.

So two things might be happening here:

- Gmail (and the other clients) does not support a protocol relative (or "schemaless") url (they might try `http` then `https`, but I don't know if they do that). To be safe I would use a full url.
- The image is not publicly accessible, even when tried with `http` or `https`. You are using a staging env, perhaps it's protected with http basic auth? Also the `.come` as TLD in `staging.mysite.come` is strange, but I assume it was just a typo...

Comment: Fantastic! It ended up being the lack of protocol. Also yes, `come` was a typo ;) Thank you!

Comment: Good to know, and glad to be of help!

Comment: Good explanation what does all these = mean.